Schedule Firebase Cloud Function Doesn't Handle DST
exports.sendDailyNotification = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 12 * * *')
    .timeZone('America/Chicago')
    .onRun(async (context) => {
        // Code Here
    }

I would expect this cloud function to run every day at 12:00 PM Chicago time. However, it appears as if it is using CST currently instead of CDT. This causes it to run at 11:00 PM Chicago time since it is currently daylight savings time. I imagine this will then run at 12:00 PM when daylight savings is over. Does Firebase not automatically adjust? How can I run this function whenever it is noon Chicago time?

I would expect that the timezone should take into account daylight savings adjustments.  If that's not what's happening, contact Firebase support to get more information.
